# .POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, war

I'm trying to generate a war using an Ant script, but it seems that it won't run on jboss. Anyone knows the diference between this and create a war using Eclipse(File ->Export -> War)?

```
<war warfile="${docflow4-web-home}/deploy/${nome}.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">        
    <fileset dir="${docflow4-web-home}/web">                
        </fileset>          
</war>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, optionally, there is a supply WAR export Options, such as whether or not to include Java™ source files in the WAR, and whether to overwrite any existing resources during the export process. Source files are not usually included in a WAR file, because they are not necessary for the server to run the web application. Otherwise, everything is similar to ant script.

In Ant script, your script seems alright, but it is aways nice using the tag , for example: `<classes dir="${classes.dir}" />` because it defines a grouping to specify what goes into the `WEB-INF\classes` folder.

If you are using some third part jar, use the tag `lib` too, example:

```
   <lib dir="thirdpartyjars">
      <exclude name="portlet.jar"/>
   </lib>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'm going to take a look on what you said.